# PyQt5: QLineEdit doesn't show inside a QGroupBox

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm creating a PyQt5 application in which I want to put some of QLineEdit widgets inside a QGroupBox.
When I run my application, GroupBox is visible and LineEdit is not.

In CreateLinesEdit() I commented a line which sets the line edit visible, but it opens lineEdit in a new window.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGroupBox, QApplication, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.BoxLayout()
        self.AddBox()
        self.CreateLinesEdit()
        self.show()

    def BoxLayout(self):
        self.groupBoxScreen = QGroupBox()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_screenGame = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_lineEdit = QHBoxLayout()

    def AddBox(self):
        self.vbox_screenGame.addItem(self.hbox_lineEdit)
        self.groupBoxScreen.setLayout(self.vbox_screenGame)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.groupBoxScreen)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def CreateLinesEdit(self):
        self.lines_edit = []
        for i in range(0, 4):
            LineEdit = QLineEdit()
            # LineEdit.setVisible(True)
            self.lines_edit.append(LineEdit)
            self.hbox_lineEdit.addWidget(self.lines_edit[i])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Change `self.vbox_screenGame.addItem(self.hbox_lineEdit)` to `self.vbox_screenGame.addLayout(self.hbox_lineEdit)` since you are adding a layout.

Comment: It's also explained in the [documentation on `addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem): "This function is not usually called in application code. To add a widget to a layout, use the addWidget() function; to add a child layout, use the addLayout() function provided by the relevant QLayout subclass."

Comment: Thanks, it's working :D